# Ag-Grid when fire onColumnResized it fire onDragStopped

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, ag-grid

I have tow function first one is ColumnResized and DragStopped the first one for to know width Column and the second one for to know Column order so the problem is that when i fire onColumnResized it fire onDragStopped and that is problem, any solution please??

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, `onDragStopped` is fired because you stopped dragging the Column Resizer.

There is an improvement request to add the event.target to DragEvents (AG-3420  add event.target in callback params for drag events (ie onDragStarted)) - See: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

For now, if possible, just ignore the drag events

Comment: how ?? give me an example because i am new in ag-grid, how to add event.target

Comment: you can't add an event.target right now. The agGrid team will add this property on the next release. For now, you will need to ignore the event.

Comment: ignore = don't do anything when `onDragStopped` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

We can stop updateing the resizing over Drag columns in the following way

```
params.target.childElementCount > 1
```

or

```
params.target.className !== 'ag-header-cell-resize'
```

In if condition we need to pass the above one of the condition

```
const onDragStopped = useCallback(params => {
        if (params.target.className !== 'ag-header-cell-resize') { // condtion to avoide resize event update
            const colIds = params.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().map(col => col.colId)
            const value = columns.sort((a, b) => colIds.indexOf(a.colId) - colIds.indexOf(b.colId))
            if (gridParams) {
                setColumns(value)
            }
        }
    }, [ gridParams, setColumns ])
```